# Multiple Network Cards (16) on Windows Operating System. Random failures with UDP/SNMP

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

Please help me with this issue. Please be patient and read through.

I have 4 (4 port ethernet cards) for a total of 16 ethernet cards on a single PC.

First Ethernet card IP(10.10.0.10) is connected to a router 1 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 Second Ethernet card IP(10.10.0.11) is connected to a router 1 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 Third Ethernet card IP(10.10.0.12) is connected to a router 1 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 Fourth Ethernet card IP(10.10.0.13) is connected to a router 1 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1

Fifth Ethernet card (10.10.0.14) is connected to a router 2 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 sixth Ethernet card (10.10.0.15) is connected to a router 2 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 7th Ethernet card (10.10.0.16) is connected to a router 2 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 8th Ethernet card (10.10.0.17) is connected to a router 2 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1

9th Ethernet card (10.10.0.18) is connected to a router 3 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 10th Ethernet card (10.10.0.19) is connected to a router 3 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 11th Ethernet card (10.10.0.20) is connected to a router 3 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 12th Ethernet card (10.10.0.21) is connected to a router 3 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1

13th Ethernet card (10.10.0.22) is connected to a router 4 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 14th Ethernet card (10.10.0.23) is connected to a router 4 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 15th Ethernet card (10.10.0.24) is connected to a router 4 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1 16th Ethernet card (10.10.0.25) is connected to a router 4 which is the gateway at 10.10.0.1

All subnets on each ethernet card are set to 255.255.255.0. The gateway of each card is set to 10.10.0.1.

All i need to do is to talk to 10.10.0.1 from each ethernet card and also talk to snmp/udp interface 192.168.100.1 on each router. That is my only objective. Talking to 10.10.0.1 automatically gets me access to 192.168.100.1. I don't need any special routing to talk to 192.168.100.1.

I have no issue with 90% of the routers models I am talking to. Everything works. However for 10% of routers models, the configuration randomly stops working with udp traffic that deal with wireless interface of modem. The ethernet card does not read data coming from the modem even though wireshark can see it.

Is there anything wrong with the configuration with regards to networking? I am thinking that all these modems are on the same network which might cause issues. If i put subnet as 255.255.255.255, will it help with none of the networks talking to each other?

I know this is not a typicall setup but it is required for the testing i need to do. Please help me with this and let me know what you think.

Comment: What I think is quite simple: Different networks connected to the same machine should have different IP ranges. Otherwise, you’re just asking for it. Also, why not make a diagram? Way better than your repetitive wall of text. ;)

Comment: I thought about that..True that but I was at home and did not have access to software. will do and maybe edit document.   When I talk to the routers, I use programming. I am binding the socket to each NIC card IP(for example to 10.10.0.10) so that it only talks to the correct 10.10.0.1 IP. I am trying to do specific actions on each NIC card, not just general access to router.